# Can I set a generic yii view string based on model instead of individual widgets

Tags: view, yii, dry, database-relations

I have set up relationships between several tables. I got the view in tableFoo to look up the Name in `tableBar` instead of showing `barId`, by putting the following into the widget:

```
array( 'label' => $model->Bar->getAttributeLabel('Bar'),
       'value' => $model->Bar->Name ),
```

But I have lots more tables, and I'd prefer to have a single place for setting these things. Is there a way to set anything with a relation to Bar to show `Bar->Name`? Or do I have to do this separately for all the `barIds`, `bazIds`, etc throughout the model?

tldr: Where is a single point of truth for displaying Name instead of ID for all related tables?